# Converting between Keras and Lasagne

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, lasagne

I am trying to combine a `Keras` model with a `Lasagne` layer. I am calling this function in the `Lasagne` layer:

```python
def get_output_for(self, inputs, deterministic=False):
    self.p = self.nonlinearity(T.dot(inputs[1], self.pi))
    self.mask = sample_mask(self.p)
    if deterministic or T.mean(self.p) == 0:
        return self.p*inputs[0]
    else:
        return inputs[0]*self.mask
```

The problem is that my `inputs` object is the output of the previous `Keras` layer, which is a  `Tesnor` object as `Keras` layers produce `Tensor` outputs. This does not work. I am not sure what type `inputs` are supposed to have or how to convert between `Tensor` and the type expected by this function.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not the best to mix Lasagne and Keras/Tensorflow objects. Instead you can convert the get_output_for method to Tensorflow. 
In what follows, I suppose that nonlinearity is similar to something like

```
self.nonlinearity = lambda x: tf.maximum(x, 0)
```

and that inputs is a numpy.array-like object:

```
def tf_get_output_for(self, inputs, deterministic=False):
    self.p = self.nonlinearity(tf.matmul(inputs[1], self.pi))
    self.mask = sample_mask(self.p)
    if deterministic or tf.reduce_mean(self.p) == 0:
        return self.p * inputs[0]
    else:
        return inputs[0] * self.mask
```

The method sample_mask has to be converted to be "Tensorflow compatible"